# What is the context of the documents that Irving finds in the box?

Tags: plot-explanation, severance

In season 1 episode 9 of Severance, Irving's innie finds a box/trunk in his outie's closet

> with what seems to be his dad's uniform (along with a picture of his dad). He then finds a compartment underneath that has multiple documents. One is a newspaper clipping of a man suing Lumon to get more information of a workplace injury; this is Irving's dad, correct?

Another document is

> a list of employees with notes on them. Was this a document acquired by his dad for the lawsuit? Or was Irving doing his own investigation into Lumon to find out what happened to his dad? Were the documents in the box there because he was hiding them from somebody? Or because he had become disillusioned with his own investigation?

A third document is

> a map that has a few names written on it (including Burt's), indicating where each of these people live. Why?

In short: what is the context of these documents? (I'm guessing some/most of this context will be revealed, in future seasons.)

Comment: I edited your question to get _at least something_ out of those spoiler tags for some context

Comment: @Luciano I thought the first sentence was a pretty big spoiler (even a friend thinks so), but I'll leave the edit for now.

Comment: The trick, really, for spoilers is to not give anything away in what becomes the first two lines you can see from the main list. After that, anyone who clicks through has made the decision to read the question. I've see npeople post 'spoilered' questions before without realising the main spoiler, right at the end of their question, ended up being there for all to see in the précis. *"At the end of Episode 9 …. who killed [main protagonist]?"* **D'oh!!**

Answer (score 4):

##### Irving's outie was investigating [Lumon](https://severance.wiki/lumon_industries) and Lumon's severed employees.

[Irving's outie's trunk](https://severance.wiki/irving_s_footlocker) contains US Navy uniforms, a picture of Irving's father in US Navy uniform, a [newspaper clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9oqi.jpg) about a severed employee suing Lumon because of an injury the employee got while working there, a list of Lumon's severed employees including their personal information and other details, an architectural plan, various documents — some with a Lumon letterhead, and a logistics invoice.

The documents imply that Irving's outie has been collating information about Lumon and Lumon's severed employees. He is recording the employees' ages, addresses, severance dates, college degrees, marital statuses, possible connections to each other, and other details.

The US Navy uniforms and picture of Irving's father in uniform imply Irving's military connection, possibly hinting at why Irving is working at and investigating Lumon.

> One is a newspaper clipping of a man suing Lumon to get more information of a workplace injury; this is Irving's dad, correct?

That man is a severed Lumon employee named Dalton Emery. Emery is suing Lumon because of a hand injury that his severed self got while working there. There is no indication that he was Irving's dad. The [newspaper clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9oqi.jpg) is just one of the pieces of information that Irving's outie was collating.

> A third document is a map that has a few names written on it (including Burt's), indicating where each of these people live. Why?

As part of his investigation, Irving's outie is recording the addresses of the severed employees and is trying to make contact with some of them. One of the names in the list has a "tried to make contact" note beside it.

Comment: On first watch, I didn't catch the name in the newspaper clipping, so I figured it was Irving's dad. Hence why I thought that it might've been his dad that started the investigation.

Comment: I think the navy connection might be there to show that both Irvings have a sense of duty and loyalty to institutions. I doubt it’s “he’s investigating because the military put him into Lumon.”

Comment: @KevinTroy That is indeed a possibility. Though, I didn't say “he’s investigating because the military put him into Lumon.”